# Which model to use for panel data?

Tags: panel-data

For my masters thesis in corporate finance I'm doing a research about debt concentration (i.e. companies using several debt types or only 1, measured by HHI index) I've got several determinants and some control variables. My data consists of 24503 observations, from 2009-2013. For some companies I have the data for all 5 years, other companies are only once or twice in the dataset. I would like to do a regression with fixed effects. (year FE and firm FE). Is this the correct choice, and why? I've also considered GEE but im not sure.

Comment: Wouldn't random effect for firm and random effect for year nested in firm be more realistic? In other words, wouldn't a hierarchical model model be more appropriate for the phenomenon's data in your hands?

Comment: Personally I have little knowledge about this. I've read some theoretical pieces which explain several nuances between different models, but my statistical background is not sufficient to clearly understand it. I know it's an easy thing to do, to ask other people to give you the answer but believe me I've put much thought and effort into trying to understand it. The only thing I can say is that in many other, similar studies, the regressions where done with fixed effects rather than random effects. It's just not enough to give only that as a reason to use FE, I need some statistical reason

Comment: I would suggest you to read a bit about Bayesian hierarchical modeling, which might be more flexible for your analysis, but I fear that that *bit* could wind up being a bit larger than a byte, tending more to be a whole hard drive, pardoning me for the IT pun.